# how to search file(s) in all the directories of c,d,e drives at a time using windows batch commands

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Manually, I am trying to search for a virus in PC. As part of this, I written a windows batch script as below.

```
@echo off

.....

:start

IF EXIST pathoengs.exe goto infected

IF EXIST pathoengs.bat goto infected

IF NOT EXIST pathoengs.bat goto statistics

IF NOT EXIST pathoengs.exe goto statistics

set Pathname="C:\"

CD %Pathname%

:infected

echo A Virus has been detected!

set /p n=Delete?(y/n)

If %n% == y del pathoengs.bat del pathoengs.exe

If %n% == n goto exit

goto start

:statistics

echo No virus

:exit

exit
```

Issue what I am facing is, my script is not able to detect the file which is present in C:\ drive or sub folders of C:\ drive.

If I search for a file in the path like C:\Users\xxx\Desktop instead of CD C:\ and write it "CD  C:\Users\xxx\Desktop" in the script then, it is searching & working fine as expected. I am not understanding, why this is failed if I try to search in C Drive like CD C:\. Am I doing something wrong here or script for the search code itself is wrong. May be the way of searching all the drives & its sub folders is different, please let me know your suggestions.

Actually, I want to search for the file(s) in all the drives (like c,d,e..) & its sub folders. If the file is present, then virus is there. So, user will go & delete the files, proceed accordingly. Otherwise, no virus is present.

Please let me know how to achieve this kind of searching using windows batch script if you have any idea. Please do the needful.

Kindly let me know if you need any more information from my end.

Thanks.

Comment: While someone may be able to help you with the technical part of your question, conceptually it's entirely wrong. You do realize this script in no sense whatsoever resembles a virus scanner, right? Is it an exercise in scripting?

Comment: Also you can't reach the line "IF NOT EXIST pathoengs.exe goto statistics". pathoengs.bat will always either exist or not exist, so you'll branch off before this.

Comment: I want to understand why wont reach this line "IF NOT EXIST". If files exist then, it wont reach this line. Otherwise it will reach rt. Please correct me if am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This should give you a file containing all those filenames on a number of drives, which you can then read to do what you need to do with them.

It doesn't avoid checking DVD drives etc, and it's slow because it has to check every part of every drive.

```
@echo off
(
   for %%a in ( c d e f g h i j k l ) do (
      if exist "%%a:\" dir "%%a:\pathoengs.exe" "%%a:\pathoengs.bat" /b /s /a-d
   )
)>"%temp%\virus list.txt"
```

Comment: Please let me know if I can use the below code to verify if the files are not existing in any of the drives then allow the user to exit immediately.

@echo off

(

for %%a in ( c d e f g h i j k l ) do (

  if not exist "%%a:\" dir "%%a:\pathoengs.exe" "%%a:\pathoengs.bat" /b /s /a-d goto exit
)

Comment: @gopi The drives still have to be searched - because without searching them the code cannot know if the files do not exist.

Comment: My question is about the below code. I would like to know, does this code works fine in case of "IF NOT EXIST"? If the search is unable to find files in any of the drives then, will the below code helps to exit from the entire search? Please let me know.                                                                                                                                                                                         @echo off
(
   for %%a in ( c d e f g h i j k l ) do (
      if exist "%%a:\" dir "%%a:\pathoengs.exe" "%%a:\pathoengs.bat" /b /s /a-d goto exit
   )
)

Answer (score 0):

```
set /p n=Delete?(y/n)

If %n% == y del pathoengs.bat del pathoengs.exe

If %n% == n goto exit
```

You did not put a `&` between two `del` command, the script should be like this:

```
choice /c:yn /m "Delete?(y/n)"

If %errorlevel% == 1 del pathoengs.bat & del pathoengs.exe

If %errorlevel% == 2 exit /b
```

Use `choice /c` is better, and use `exit /b` to exit instead.